# Unlocking Samsung S10 to first page of home screen

Tags: settings, lock-screens, home-screen, samsung-galaxy-s-10

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S10. I am trying to find a way to go to my default home screen (the first page of home screens) every time I unlock my phone. I tried MacroDroid and AutomateIt.

Comment: Tell us what you tried with MacroDroid and AutomateIt.

Comment: MacroDroid seems to be working fine with Nova Launcher. I set it to go to home screen when device unlocks and it does that fine. Which launcher are you using and are you certain that screen you are targeting is indeed the Home screen?

Comment: it throws me to the last used "main / home screens" but not the first(marked as default" one   i told it to when phone unlocks to go to home screen